# How to use getChartLayoutInterface() with a Pie Chart for dynamic positioning in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am attempting to dynamically render an element over a Google Chart. This is supposedly supported by the API for all chart types.

I copied the sample code from [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays)

I modified the options to be appropriate for a Pie chart. I changed the line

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line-chart-marker'));
```

to call the constructor for PieChart instead. I read the rest of the sample code and nothing else is (supposedly) specific to the LineChart. Google Charts API shows that  [PieChart contains all the same methods used in LineChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#methods) for this example.

However, this does not work for PieChart. From the console log, getChartLayoutInterface() still returns a valid object. But this line

```
document.querySelector('.overlay-marker').style.top = Math.floor(cli.getYLocation(dataTable.getValue(5, 1))) - 50 + "px";
```

and the similar line for X location appear to be the root of the problem, specifically these calls cli.getYLocation(dataTable.getValue(5, 1)) which return "undefined" whereas in the LineChart implementation they return valid positions as numbers. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Havn't worked with the getChartLayoutInterface, but isn't the returned numbers references to where the actual value is presented in the graph, and the PieChart doens't really have "dots" for representing the value.

Just a thought.

Comment: that's true. if there were they would be more useful in polar coordinates, not Cartesian as the ChartLayoutInterface suppodedly returns. Had not given that much thought.